# Trouble with MySQL code on WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mysqli

I'm working on a custom functions.php file for simplified templating on WordPress. Works great on my localhost but on a clients server it doesn't seem to be doing the MySQL... No error is being displayed so it is connecting correctly. But it isn't reading the variables in the `foreach()`...

Below is a sample of the code. The `echo $result` displays nothing. The `echo "HELLO WORLD!<BR/>"` prints on the screen 5 times. No matter what the query it seems to print 5 times...

```
$db_connect = mysqli_connect( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME ) OR die ( 'Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );

$query = '
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        ' . $table_prefix . 'options
';

$results = mysqli_query( $db_connect, $query );

foreach( $results as $result ) {
    echo $result;
    echo "HELLO WORLD!<BR/>";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to fetch the results using [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) or mysqli_fetch_array()

```
if ($results = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print_r($row)
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I'm curious now as to why it worked on my localhost before but not server? Thanks.

Comment: @CoryNickerson: that's impossible!

Comment: Was working just fine on my local install of wordpress... o.O

Answer (score 1):

You beat me Akam, indeed its missing the

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) { .. }
```